# Why is Code Signing Not Available in XCode 4.3.2 File-New?

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to create an ad-hoc distribution profile for the first time to use w/ Test Flight. The first step is to create an entitlements file by going to File-New and then selecting Code Signing in the left panel. However, there is no Code Signing listed.

[image]

Do I have to configure something to get this option to be displayed?

Comment: Where are you reading that you need this?